Can I post a non-signed MSIX app on the Microsoft store?
I just created an app that I want to publish to the Microsoft Store, so I packed it into MSIX format but I get this message when trying to launch the package (see picture):

This app package is not signed with a trusted certificate. Contact your system administrator or the app developer to obtain a new certificate or app package with trusted certificates. The root certificate and all immediate certificates of the signature in the app package must be trusted (0x800B010A).


And that is correct, I don't have a certificate. In fact, I don't want to buy one at the moment. I read in a Microsoft article that non-signed apps could be submitted to the Microsoft Store (see picture).
So, my question is: will this app work if I submit it to the Microsoft Store?


Yes, you don't have to buy a code-signing certificate to publish the app in the store.
But you do not need to make sure you set the specific CN in the package manifest, assigned to you by MS when you reserved the app name in the store.
Here is an article where we share more details on the steps required:
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html
If you're using Visual Studio to build the MSIX package, just make sure you are logged into VS with the same account you log in to the MS Store and Visual Studio will synchronize this info in your application manifest.
